# How to do something with Bash when a text line appears in a file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to run a command as soon as a certain text appears in a log file. How do I do that in Bash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use command

```
tail -f file.log | grep --line-buffered "my pattern" | while read line
do
  echo $line
done
```

The `--line-buffered` is the key here, otherwise the read will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Using only `tail`:

```
tail -f file.log | while read line; do if [[ $line == *text* ]]; then
    mycommand
fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work even without GNU grep:

```
tail -f -n 0 logfile.out | nawk '/pattern/ {system("echo do something here")}'
```

edit: Added "-n 0" so that only new occurences of the text will be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Also you might look at `inotail`, a replacement for `tail -f` which uses the `inotify` framework to wake up only when the file you're interested in has changed. The usual `tail -f` just sleeps for short periods of time between polling, which is an effective but not very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like matli's answer.   Bruno De Fraine's answer is also good in that it uses only shell ccommands, not other programs (like awk).  It suffers from the problem that the entire line must match the magic string.  It's not clear from the question that's part of the requirment.

I would modify it a tiny bit to deal with the "as soon as" clause in the original question

```
logfile_generator | tee logfile.out | nawk '/pattern/ {system("echo do something here")}'
```

where logfile_generator is the program that is generating the log file in the first place.  This modification executes the "something" as soon as the magic string is located.

Comment: My solution matches any line that contains "text" (that's what the pattern *text* does), not only lines equal to "text". See the description of the [[ ]] compound and == in the Bash manual.